# Removing pseudo element based user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one use the user's interaction with an html element to remove a pseudo element? I have an element with a pseudo element, which has 50% width and absolutely positioned. I would like to remove the pseudo element permanently once its parent has been interacted with by the user.

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.test::before {
  content: "some text";
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
```

Using :hover, :active and :focus on the parent doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Wihle there are ways to interact with pseudo-elements in JS, a far easier method to do what you require in this case is to associate the psuedo-element with a CSS class, then use JS to add/remove/toggle that class under whatever event you need.

Here's a working example of that concept:

```js
const testElement = document.querySelector('.test');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  testElement.classList.toggle('foo');
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  background: #00C;
}

.foo::before {
  content: "some text";
  background: #C00;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="test foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div><br />

<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try an animation with the `visibility` property

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.test::before {
  content: "some text";
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: hide .1s forwards paused;
}

/* consider whatever interaction you want in the selector */
:is(.test:hover,.test:focus,.test:active):before {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes hide {
  to {visibility: hidden;}
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
```